# Unable to Show imageView in recyclerVIew synchronously with TTS

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, text-to-speech

How can i show/Hide imageView in recyclerView as TTS(text to speech) plays for all the available list items, one by one!

**Activity method**
-This method is called r with Loop(not working, no bugs but simply do not give my expected output

```
    int position=0;
    public void convertTextToSpeech() {
        Multiples multiples1=items.get(position);
        for (Multiples item : items) {

            text = item.first + "  " + item.getSecond() + " Za " + item.getResult() + ".";
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            boolean speakingEnd = tts.isSpeaking();

            if (speakingEnd) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Speaking...."+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                multiples1.setImage_show(true);
                mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done...."+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            position++;
        }
    }
```

The complete code is below for more understanding,

First, i displayed all items in recyclerView. Afterward, I am calling the displayed item in a method having for loop to TTS play each rows(list item).  The problem i am facing now is the imageView is not displaying as each recyclerView item are being read by TTS.

Expected output is whenever TTS plays for each row item textView, An imageView(#image1) should show simultaneously

---

---

---

## **UPDATED TRIED CODE**

DisplayActivityResultAdapter.java

```
    ......
    .......
    int position = 0;
    public void convertTextToSpeech() {
        Multiples multiples1=items.get(position);
        for (Multiples item : items) {
            text = item.first + "  " + item.getSecond() + " Za " + item.getResult() + ".";
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
            boolean speakingEnd = tts.isSpeaking();

            // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Speaking...."+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
           // multiples1.setImage_show(true);
            //  mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);
           // Log.i("values","------------------------------------------Row value-"+item.getFirst()+" X "+item.getSecond()+", Position="+position);
             //------------------------
            MyAdapter m= (MyAdapter)  mAdapter;
            m.updateItem(item,position);
            position++;
        }
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
    .....
    .....
    // Replace the contents of a view (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // - get element from your dataset at this position
        // - replace the contents of the view with that element

        if (holder instanceof MyAdapter.MyViewHolder) {
            final MyAdapter.MyViewHolder view = (MyAdapter.MyViewHolder) holder;
            Multiples p = items.get(position);
            view.name.setText(p.first + " X " + p.getSecond() + "= "+p.getResult());

            if(position>0) {
                if (p.image_show) {
                    view.image1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    view.image.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                } else {
                    view.image1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    view.image.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public void updateItem(Multiples newItem, int pos) {
        Log.i("values","-----In updateItem Log----Row value-"+newItem.getFirst()+" X "+newItem.getSecond()+", Position="+pos);
        items.set(pos, newItem); //update passed value in your adapter's data structure
        Log.e("msg","-----items.get(pos)------------->"+items.get(pos).getFirst()+" X " +items.get(pos).getSecond());

        notifyItemChanged(pos,newItem);
    }

    // Return the size of your dataset (invoked by the layout manager)
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return items.size();
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is your recycler adapter? Generally, your tts code should invoke your adapter to switch the image in the recycler item's image view and invoke  notifyItemChanged.

Comment: @MDNaseemAshraf All information is present in the question. Please try to post an answer or provide me tips

Comment: Are you use git? Can you provide link to your git repository?

Comment: @Monkey appears as if you're missing a picture `Adapter: [![enter image description here][1]][1]`

Comment: @StackDanny that image was expired. So i removed it. Instead, i have added adapter code in above question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You main fail is absence of listener for TTS. Without it you don't know when you should update your `RecyclerView`.
Listener can looks like this:

```
class MyListener extends UtteranceProgressListener {
        @Override
        public void onStart(String utteranceId) {
            int currentIndex = Integer.parseInt(utteranceId);
            mMainAdapter.setCurrentPosition(currentIndex);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mMainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
            int currentIndex = Integer.parseInt(utteranceId);
            mMainAdapter.setCurrentPosition(-1);
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    mMainAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            if (currentIndex < data.size() - 1) {
                playSound(currentIndex + 1);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(String utteranceId) {
        }
    }
```

I've created a test project to show how it can be implemented. [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ku-gbJ-evIc) you can see how it works. [Here](https://github.com/rt1shnik/TextToSpeechExample) is my github repository.

Answer (score -1):

Put the below code snippet inside your `Adapter` in `OnBindViewHolder`

```
        text = item.first + "  " + item.getSecond() + " Za " + item.getResult() + ".";
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        boolean speakingEnd = tts.isSpeaking();


        if(speakingEnd){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Speaking...."+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            multiples1.setImage_show(true);
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(position);

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Done...."+position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

May this help Thanks.

Comment: writing tts is not allowed in the method onBindViewHolder at adpter!

Answer (score -1):

Please check this out. In your code, you are missed `UtteranceProgressListener`.
You have to add `UtteranceProgressListener` which will give you speech completion listener events. Also, you will need utteranceID which will be passed to `tts.speak()` that helps you to identify the speech if you need it.
Take a variable as,

```
String utterId = "";
```

then in your `TextToSpeech` `onInit` before calling `convertTextToSpeech` register this listener to your tts.

```
...
else{
 tts.setOnUtteranceProgressListener(new UtteranceProgressListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onStart(String utteranceId) {

                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onDone(String utteranceId) {
                                        convertTextToSpeech(position);
                                    }

                                    @Override
                                    public void onError(String utteranceId) {

                                    }
                                });
                                convertTextToSpeech(0);
}
```

Initially, 0 is passed to `convertTextToSpeech` as it is the first time call. Here I've made some changes to the `convertTextToSpeech`. In this, I've removed the loop you were using earlier instead, it will be a recursive function.

```
 public void convertTextToSpeech(int pos) {
        if (pos >= items.size()) return;
        position = pos;
        final Multiples multiples = items.get(position);

        text = multiples.first + "  " + multiples.getSecond() + " Za " + multiples.getResult() + ".";

        utterId = (new Random().nextInt() % 9999999) + ""; // "" is String force

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Bundle params = new Bundle();
            params.putString(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, utterId);

            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params, utterId);
        } else {
            HashMap<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_UTTERANCE_ID, utterId);

            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, params);
        }

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                MyAdapter m = (MyAdapter) mAdapter;
                multiples.setImage_show(true);
                m.updateItem(multiples, position);
                position++;
            }
        });

    }
```

As you can see the `tts.speak()` is deprecated you should use the new one to avoid issues in the latest android os.

In your `MyAdapter`, you have to set previous item `image_show` to false.

```
public void updateItem(Multiples newItem, int pos) {
    if (pos > 0) {
        items.get(pos - 1).setImage_show(false);
    }
    Log.i("values", "-----In updateItem Log----Row value-" + newItem.getFirst() + " X " + newItem.getSecond() + ", Position=" + pos);
    items.set(pos, newItem); //update passed value in your adapter's data structure
    Log.e("msg", "-----items.get(pos)------------->" + items.get(pos).getFirst() + " X " + items.get(pos).getSecond());

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Check the gif uploaded. Please keep us updated.

[image]

If you need any help you can ask. Thanks